# Navigation and when is activity started from a task that belongs to another app?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-navigation

From the docs about navigation (emphasis mine):

> However, using navigateUpFromSameTask() is suitable only when your app
>   is the owner of the current task (that is, the user began this task
>   from your app). **If that's not true and your activity was started in a
>   task that belongs to a different app**, then navigating Up should create
>   a new task that belongs to your app, which requires that you create a
>   new back stack.

What are some examples of `your activity was started in a task that belongs to a different app`? I can only think of deep linking

Answer (score 0):

Your app can register itself to be a [handler for intents](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html), such as dialing, camera, and shared links or text. In this case, if a user chooses your app, its calling activity will technically be the parent in the hierarchy, so the navigation up would return the user to the previous app.

Comment: Is that an application of deeplinking?

Comment: This is not the same process as deep linking. Deep linking is the process of allowing your app to be opened by a URL or intent with parameters to navigate to a certain place, or prefill certain information.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can be opened by other apps trough explicit intent.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, "your.app.package.ActivityName");
```

Other sources of opening the app in any arbitrary activity is trough:
Notifications or AlarmManagers, all those runs on PendingIntents.

In both cases, there's no stack-back cause your app didnt come from a stack.